# Show that $\mathbb{R}$ is equinumerous with $0$ to $\pi r$

Tags: geometry

I know there should be some geometrical argument that shows this, because $\pi$ is an infinite decimal, but I'm not sure how I would go about constructing one. I'm not really looking for a bijection (if it's not necessary), but rather a way to intuitively understand why the two are equal.

Comment: What do you mean with "$0$ to $\pi r$"? The interval $(0,\pi r)$ for some $r>0$? Actually, $\mathbb R$ is equinumerous with *any* interval of positive length.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but: Draw a half circle of radius $r$ sans its endpoints with "curved part down" and an axis underneath it. Consider the rays from the "center" of the half circle to the axis.

Comment: @DavidMitra this is precisely what I mean. A half circle with radius 1 that spans from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the bijective map everyone has in his mind to do what you want:

[image: Small Sketch]

Comment: Wow. That's pretty interesting.

Comment: What about the endpoints? =]

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I assume "$0$ to $\pi r$" doesn't include the endpoints (i.e. it means $(0,\pi r)$.)